# Animation in WillDisplayCellForRow

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

I have a scaling animation that has to be done when one cell shrinks . I am able to do scaling in the cell that gets expanded but the same animation doesn't happen when shrinked. -Using `CATransformMakeScale` in `WillDisplayRowAtIndexPath`.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ( self.previousSelectedSection != -1 && self.previousSelectedSection ==  indexPath.section) {
        cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        cell.alpha = 0;
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"scaleTableViewCellAnimationID" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        cell.alpha = 1;
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
     }
     else if(self.previousSelectedSection != -1 && self.selectedSection ==  indexPath.section){
        cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        cell.alpha = 0;
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"scaleTableViewCellAnimationID" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        cell.alpha = 1;
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: I had posted my code, please do check it